# Prevent infinity loop builds when job push to github and triggers the webhook

Tags: jenkins, github, webhooks

I have a Github project with a webhook to trigger the build on Jenkins.
It works pretty well. I used the option "Trigger builds remotely" from Jenkins.

In the final steps of the build, it updates some files to update the package version, and submit it back to github.

This triggers a new build, generating an infinity loop of builds.

How to prevent this extra build to be triggered?

I tried the option "Polling ignores commits from certain users" to prevent builds from the bot user. but it seems to work only with the Polling process, and not the remote trigger.